# Calling SH script from RubyOnRails View - Passing arguments and redirecting to an html file on the filesystem afterwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to ruby, i've stumbled into the following issue while trying to execute a SH script from within a view (index.html.erb). I have done the following:

app\views\tests\index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Run it', :action=>'callthis' %>
```

app\controllers\tests_controller.rb

```
def callthis
  puts "I was called!"
      # system call here
end
```

I'm getting the following error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"callthis", controller=>"tests"}):
app/views/tests/index.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_tests_index_html_erb__911976670__617626598'
app/views/tests/index.html.erb:4:in `each'
app/views/tests/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_tests_index_html_erb__911976670__617626598'
app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Edit:
    Routes

```
tests     GET    /tests(.:format)                             tests#index
          POST   /tests(.:format)                             tests#create
new_test  GET    /tests/new(.:format)                         tests#new
edit_test GET    /tests/:id/edit(.:format)                    tests#edit
test      GET    /tests/:id(.:format)                         tests#show
          PUT    /tests/:id(.:format)                         tests#update
      DELETE /tests/:id(.:format)                         tests#destroy
```

Edit 2:
Thanks Zippy, I see hello is output, however, it also gives me the following error:

```
Hello
Started GET "/tests/callthis" for 10.10.9.141 at Wed Mar 13 16:29:22 -0400 2013
Processing by TestsController#callthis as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template tests/callthis, application/callthis with     {:handlers=>[:erb, :builde
:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en]}. Searched in:
  * "/mnt/wt/ruby/wtrorp/app/views"
):
```

Edit 3:

From the 'tests' view, I am only looking to execute the 'callthis' defined in the 'testscontroller'. That def will just be a system call to execute an SH script, and redirect to the output file it generates to the filesystem. 
I am looking to pass it two args: a string (which is in the test object 'test.script') and an id (which i want to pull from the browser session). I realize the problem just got a lot harder and will update the header question to reflect it :D

```
system(./callthis.sh test.script $my_id_var)
```

Edit 4:

I am looking to generate a file from the sh script, and redirect to a static. The static page will catch a variable, and know which file the sh script generated, so that it may display it in a frame of that static page. Maybe out of the context of this question, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: how does your declaration inside of routes.rb look like?

Comment: you don't have that route in your routes.rb file

Comment: you have to put a view also in the `app/views/tests`. Do you wish to render a view with this? Maybe not, just some action and be redirected to another page? then you wouldn't need a view.. Update your question even more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this for starters:

**config/routs.rb**

```
resources :tests do
  collection do
    get 'callthis'
  end
end
```

or if you won't have multiple routes like this you can do: (same thing)

```
resources :tests do
  get 'callthis', :on => :collection
end
```

Also, just a tip: Don't name your actions like `callthis`. No one here knows what that action is trying to do nor will you when some time passes by.
Hope i helped.

EDIT: after the questioner update the routes and after i read the question further i would recomment just one thing:

Declare your `callthis` controller like:

```
def callthis
   #perform your sh script
   redirect to tests_path
end
```

Comment: put a `EDIT` mark and nicely update your question with this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the Missing Template error, you need to either render a template, redirect to a valid url, or at least call something like 'render :nothing' or 'head :ok' in order to tell rails how to respond to the user's browser.

Be very careful about sanitizing any user inputs, including the id you say you're pulling out of the session. Assume the user might have figured out how to maliciously modify it to do something bad, and check it against a whitelist, maybe only digits or  something of that sort. Running a shell script like this is unherently unsafe, unless you're very paranoid and careful. And everyone else maintaining the app is as well.

Comment: oh yeah, `render :nothing`. I read about it just today and thank you for giving this as a super example when to use it!

Comment: sockmonk, what http method would you suggest him to use? a get? (he is not using a form or anything like that and he doesn't need any authentication_key)

Comment: Yes, since he is getting information from the server but not trying to change information on the server, a GET request seems appropriate by RESTful conventions, and also happens to be easy to implement that way.